# Refresh the aside without new page

Tags: php, html

So i have the following code for the aside which allows the user to search for other user(NOTE: i have left out the aside-tag here in order to make the code more readable):

```html
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for Friends" name="search_name">
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="search-submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

After than i get the data from the database and display them in a variable whicht is called $output:

```html
<?php
           echo @$output;
?>
```

Ok so now when the user clicks on a name it should load the chatwindow in the aside instead of the search results. So the $output should be replaced with the chat window which has the following code:

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['chat-submit'])) {
             echo '<form method="POST" action="index.php" class="form-back">
                   <input class="back" type="submit" name="back" value="←Back">
                   </form>
                   <form>
                   <div class="chatwith"><h1><?php echo $username; echo ":"; ?></div>
                   <?php echo $finalstatus; ?>
                   <form action="index.php" method="POST" class="message-form">
                   <input class="message" type="text" placeholder="message" name="message">
                   <input class="submit" type="submit" name="message-submit" value="Send">
                   </form>';
}
?>
```

ok so both codes are working fine but when i click on one of the $outputs (and activate "chat-submit") than the old form from the search box is still there. How can i remove the old form so that only the chatwindows will be shown. Is there some kind "refresh only the aside"? If you have any questions please ask me.

Comment: How do you send the request? Is it AJAX or just direct?

Comment: @DieterKräutl no it`s just direct

Comment: Can u post the code that is suppose to replace the $output? I mean where you actually replace it.

Comment: @DieterKräutl $output should be replaced with the code inside the if-statement. So when you click on chat-submit(=inside $output) than the chat should be loaded. Indeed it loads the form but the search box and search-button from the previous form is still there

Comment: I understand. Show me what you have done to replace $output.

Comment: @DieterKräutl  i dont have that part anymore because it didnt work. i just put $output inside an if and declared a variable before that called $refresh. So when $refresh == 0 it should load $output. And inside the other if statement for the chat i put at the and $refresh = 1. but that didnt work for me.

Comment: That should work... I cant find your bug if you got no code...

Comment: @DieterKräutl ok so i habe restored the file until these ,,if-idea‘‘. : `<aside> <?php $refresh = 0; if($refresh == 0){ echo '@$output; }  if (isset($_POST['chat-submit'])) {              echo '//here goes the chat-form but this is too long for this comment. But its the same as above'; } ?> </aside>`

Comment: @DieterKräutl if you want we can talk german. This would be easier for me.

Comment: Schau dir meine Antwort an.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $refresh to 0 you dont need the if. Because it is always 0. Do like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['chat-submit'])) { 
  echo '//here goes the chat-form but this is too long for this comment. But its the   same as above'; }
else {
  echo $output;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it does work now this is the right solution from @Dieter Kräutl:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['chat-submit'])) { 
  echo '<form method="POST" action="index.php" class="form-back">
                   <input class="back" type="submit" name="back" value="←Back">
                   </form>
                   <form>
                   <div class="chatwith"><h1><?php echo $username; echo ":"; ?></div>
                   <?php echo $finalstatus; ?>
                   <form action="index.php" method="POST" class="message-form">
                   <input class="message" type="text" placeholder="message" name="message">
                   <input class="submit" type="submit" name="message-submit" value="Send">
                   </form>'; }
else {
  echo $output;
}
?>
```